# String.split() java not working

Tags: java

I have a string  completeString

```
String completeString = "Comp 30440 Software Engineering Project|20-credit module|Is part of your(Conversion) Programme.Deals with the creation of a twitter sentiment analysis application";
```

I am trying to split this string using

```
String[] array = completeString.split("|");
```

and when I am getting the first element

```
String first = array[0];
```

I am getting empty string. For next two elements I am getting only first letters i.e C and O (Comp).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`|` needs to be escaped so

`\\|` should do the trick